# How can I format a number to 2 decimal places in Perl?

Tags: perl

What is best way to format a number to 2 decimal places in Perl?

For example:

```
10      -> 10.00
10.1    -> 10.10
10.11   -> 10.11
10.111  -> 10.11
10.1111 -> 10.11
```

Comment: `printf` / `sprintf` `"%.2f"`

Comment: See the Perl FAQ at http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq4.html Search for "decimal places".

Comment: Be careful with rounding with sprintf. It sometimes doesn't round calculated numbers that end in .49 correctly, because the 2.49 is not stored as 2.49, it's stored as something like 2.49999999999999.

Answer (score 33):

It depends on how you want to truncate it.

[`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) with the `%.2f` format will do the normal "round to half even".

```
sprintf("%.2f", 1.555);  # 1.56
sprintf("%.2f", 1.554);  # 1.55
```

`%f` is a floating point number (basically a decimal) and `.2` says to only print two decimal places.

---

If you want to truncate, not round, then use `int`.  Since that will only truncate to an integer, you have to multiply it and divide it again by the number of decimal places you want to the power of ten.

```
my $places = 2;
my $factor = 10**$places;
int(1.555 * $factor) / $factor;  # 1.55
```

---

For any other rounding scheme use [Math::Round](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Round).

Comment: `sprintf("%.2f", 1.115)` returns `1.11` (at least in perl v5.32.1 x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi) though.. Why?

Comment: @MatijaNalis Floating point error. If you use "%.20f" you'll see it's really 1.1499999999999999112

Comment: To be more precise: `%.2f` means to print as a floating point number with *exactly* two decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments to @Schwern answer, trying to round via `sprintf()` will experience floating point errors, which is bad (especially if dealing e.g. with finances).

This is the solution which **correctly** rounds (instead of truncating) numbers.

```perl
sub round($$)
{
  my ($value, $places) = @_;
  my $factor = 10**$places;
  return int($value * $factor + 0.5) / $factor; # +0.5 is magical sauce to do rounding instead of truncating
}

use feature 'say';
say round(1.555, 2); # 1.56
say round(1.554, 2); # 1.55
say round(1.115, 2); # 1.12 (sprintf fails with 1.11 !) 
say round(1.114, 2); # 1.11
```