# Using perl to round number

Tags: perl, one-liner

I am having a file with numbers in MB units and I wanted to make them in GB then I found a very interesting perl to do this

```
perl -pe 's{(?<!\d)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\d)}{$1/1024}ge'
```

But I still need to round the results 2 digits after the dot

Currently, results like `260.676914215088`

I tried some other Unix tools like `cut` and `bc` but it would be better if done within Perl.

BTW the file contains numbers and strings and the above Perl is working as expected but I still need to round results.

I would appreciate if someone helped with the above perl statement as I am already using it to change between different units

Comment: Would this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35043874/how-can-i-format-a-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-perl

Comment: this didn't answer my question I would appreciate if someone helped with the above perl statement as I am already using it to change between different units

Comment: sprintf is not an option on my os

Comment: What operating system is that? Please give us all the information or we can't help you. `sprintf` is a core Perl built-in, that's about as system-agnostic as it gets. I've undone the duplicate close now.

Comment: I thought I should send results to sprintf command! it seems as you mentioned sprintf is a Perl built-in function  but I still won't be able to use it with the above Perl line, a little help would be appreciated, it's aix

Comment: @simbabque I believe his issue is not perl, but integrating the printf into his oneliner

Comment: @user2141046 correct

Comment: BTW, I found it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56595074/find-and-divide-all-numbers-in-a-file-using-sed and left a comment there but not sure if they can update a new answer for the old question

Comment: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=642337 has some interesting examples, including a pointer to Number::Format::Human

Answer (score 3):

You can embed the [`sprintf`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf) call into your substitution. You already have [the `/e` modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Other-Modifiers), so you can run that command in the substitution part and pass it the calculation you're doing.

```
#                                         VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV        V 
perl -pe 's{(?<!\d)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\d)}{sprintf("%.02f", $1/1024)}ge'
```

See it in action here:

```
$ echo "1234567" | perl -pe 's{(?<!\d)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\d)}{sprintf("%.02f", $1/1024)}ge'  
1205.63
```

Comment: That exactly what I was looking for !! Thanks @simbabque

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with a one-liner, there's no limit to the number of pipes you can give it, so just add this to your line: `perl -n -e 'printf ("%.2f\n",$_)'`

meaning
`perl -pe 's{(?<!\d)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\d)}{$1/1024}ge'| perl -n -e 'printf ("%.2f\n",$_)'`

e.g.

```
> echo "12014.324\n10123123.1\n20123.5555" | perl -pe 's{(?<!\d)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\d)}{$1/1024}ge' | perl -n -e 'printf ("%.2f\n", $_)'
11.73
9885.86
19.65
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn’t work, it gave zeros, please note the file is including other characters and strings

Comment: sample of my data:: 
size      = 98566144
total     = 68334889
actual      = 3023123

Comment: Thanks @user2141046 the other answer worked as expected